# How to make a PATCH request in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to send a PATCH request to my NodeJS API from my react frontend. I want a situation whereby if you click the edit button, the initial name price appears on the input for necessary editing. Then after editing, you can update it. Displaying the initial data works fine, but saving it doesn't work. I get the error:

> "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

I've looked up the cleanup function, but couldn't make a headway.
Below is my code:

```
const EditUserForm = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  let routeId = match.params.id;
  console.log(routeId);

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});

  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [price, setPrice] = useState();

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setItem({ ...item, [name]: value});
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateProduct();
    history.push('/');
  }
   
  const updateProduct = () => {
    fetch(`/addproducts/${routeId}`, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: item.name,
        price: item.price 
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setItem(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log('error: ', err))
      
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/products/${routeId}`, requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setName(result.product.name);
          setPrice(result.product.price);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )

  }, []);

  return (        
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <label>Name</label>
      <input 
        type="text"
        name="name"
        defaultValue={name}
        onChange={handleInputChange} 
      />

      <label>Price</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="price" 
        defaultValue={price}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />

      <button type="submit">Update</button>
      <button>
        Cancel
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default EditUserForm
```

Comment: Does your api work well in postman?

Comment: Have you tried other methods? i.e. GET, POST

Comment: The API is working very well in Postman. The GET and POST requests are as well working. @FirstArachne

Answer (score 0):

inside "**handleSubmit**" you are calling "**history.push('/')**" which produces the error, if you want to change the route then call it in **.then** of **updateProduct**

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect function is applied to each and every rendering and is not cancellable, try rewriting it like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    fetch(`/products/${routeId}`, {signal, ...requestOptions})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setName(result.product.name);
          setPrice(result.product.price);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
      return controller.abort //so the fetch request can be canceled if the effect is re-executed
  }, [routeId]); //only needs to rerun on route change
```

I am not too sure if the handles submit might cause similar problems, in which case you'd want to do something similar to this.

Comment: I've tried out the code, it's still not updating. It doesn't show up any error message either

Comment: What is not updating exactly? If you expect the UI to update then it won't because you are binding the state to defaultValue and not value.

Comment: The data in the database is not updating, even though on my console, I get a success message.

Comment: can you share that then?